# This external site rehosts the entirety of Stack Overflow without credit

Tags: discussion

The site [code.i-harness.com](https://code.i-harness.com) hosts all Stack Overflow questions in different languages. From what I can tell, the other languages are at least partially just bad (Google-)translations of the English questions and answers.

This site is probably using the Stack Overflow API in the background, since the question numbers in their URLs are just the hexadecimal encoded Stack Overflow questions. Example: [Stack Overflow 11227809](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) -> [their AB52A1](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/ab52a1)

All of this wouldn't be as bad, would it not be for three things:

- No credit in *any* form: No links to Stack Overflow, no names of creators, nothing
- They are excluding the accepted answer (and a few other answers). This means you will not find the answer that solved the question. (They also seem to have some kind of filter for questions, so you won't find all.)
- The translations they have are sometimes wrong:

  - [EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981073/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-java-and-precisely-what-information-does-it-con) [Second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981085/8472976), under the yellow box: *We do care.*
  - [DE](https://code.i-harness.com/de/q/ef851) First Answer, under the yellow box: *Es ist uns egal.* This is the *opposite* of the English one (it means *We don't care.*)

By the way, the documentation section they have are also just copies without credit. (In the case of Python, of the official Python documentation at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/).)

Because they don't have a *Contact us*, I am not really sure what can be done, so I am asking here. I would strongly say that something should be done, since they are not giving credit and (at least sometimes) giving wrong information.